# Getting SVN repos info for fresh Trac install

Tags: svn, trac

I was wondering if it is possible to get the subversion timeline information of an existing repository to show up in a fresh Trac installation?

I currently see that if I have an existing repository that Trac only sees the part of the svn timeline from the moment Trac was installed and doesn't show any of the commits before that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-sync trac with the repository using trac-admin.

```
repository resync <repos> [rev]

Re-synchronize trac with repositories

When [rev] is specified, only that revision is synchronized. Otherwise, the
complete revision history is synchronized. Note that this operation can
take a long time to complete. If synchronization gets interrupted, it can
be resumed later using the `sync` command.

To synchronize all repositories, specify "*" as the repository.
```

Comment: Just for clarity. The actual command is: trac-admin <yourprojenv> resync

Comment: Sorry mate. I had to take away the 'excepted answer' since it wasn't working 100%.

Comment: Sorry. My bad! Excepted again.